# google API's 403 error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I use Google API by OAuth2.0, but some is OK, some is error.

```
Server responded with: 403, <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>You are not authorized to access this API</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>You are not authorized to access this API</H1>
<H2>Error 403</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

that is why?

Comment: It's just a guess, but I suspect you might not be authorized to access that API...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible reasons:-

1. When I try to access using a authentication key, which is either not registered or the daily limit is exceeded, I get the error:

   ```
   {
           "error": {
             "errors": [
              {
               "domain": "usageLimits",
               "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
               "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up",
               "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
              }
             ],
             "code": 403,
             "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"
           }
           }
   ```
2. http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/docs/admin/en/gads/admin/troubleshooting_common.html

Comment: thanks,Burhan Khalid.but I used API without OAuth2.0,that's OK!I can not understand.